# How to check for specific letters in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, encryption, python-idle

I am having a problem with my Python 3 encryption program. I am writing code that uses comparisons to check for certain letters in `userMessage`, using `if` statements, and `for` loops. The problem that I am having is that the alphabet pops up between each letter of the encrypted output. For example, if the output is supposed to be `amxer`, it is `aAmBxCeDr`. Also the second `if` statement that checks for `vwxyz` is making `vwxyz` pop up between the symbols that are encrypted from rolling `vwxyz` 5 times to the right in ASCII. The second `if` statement is to change those symbols into the letters `abcde`.

```
#Start
#variables
encryptedMessage=""
userMessage = input("your message here: ")
userMessage =userMessage.lower()
shift=5
#function
def step2():
    #for loop
    for character in userMessage:
        #5:50AM February 24th, 2020
        #looking for global variable
        global encryptedMessage
        if character== "a"or"b"or"c"or"d"or"e"or"f"or"g"or"h"or"i"or"j"or"k"or"l"or"m"or"n"or"o"or"p"or"q"or"r"or"s"or"t"or"u":
            eN = ord(character)
            eN+= shift
            encryptedMessage+=chr(eN)  
        #checking for letters that go to random symbols
        if character=="v"or"w"or"x"or"y"or"z":

            if character=="v": character=="a"
            if character=="w": character=="b"
            if character=="x": character=="c"
            if character=="y": character=="d"
            if character=="z": character=="e"
            encryptedMessage+=character

step2()
print(userMessage)
print(encryptedMessage)
```

My code has an output of:

```
your message here: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
fagbhcidjekflgmhniojpkqlrmsntoupvqwrxsytzu{v|w}x~yz
>>>
```

Comment: Your comparisons can't work. `character == 'a' or 'b'` is same  as `(character == 'a') or 'b'`, which is always True since `b is not None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using is an invalid syntax. `character == 'a' or 'b'` is same as `(character == 'a') or 'b', which is always`True`since`'b' is not None`.

If you want to use multiple equals, you have to write them out as `character == 'a' or character == 'b' or ...`.

Alternatively, much better solution (as shown below) is using `set()` and the `in` operator, which checks whether the character is inside the set, and returns True if it finds it.

```
encryptedMessage=""
userMessage = input("you'r message here: ")
userMessage =userMessage.lower()
shift=5
#function
FIRST= set(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u"])
SECOND = set(["v","w","x","y","z"])
def step2():
    #for loop
    for character in userMessage:
        #5:50AM February 24th, 2020
        #looking for global variable
        global encryptedMessage
        if character in FIRST:
            eN = ord(character)
            eN+= shift
            encryptedMessage+=chr(eN)  
        #checking for letters that go to random symbols
        if character in SECOND:
            if character=="v": character=="a"
            if character=="w": character=="b"
            if character=="x": character=="c"
            if character=="y": character=="d"
            if character=="z": character=="e"
            encryptedMessage+=character

step2()
print(userMessage)
print(encryptedMessage)
```

And since i only now realised this is a simple rotation cypher, here is another example of how to implement this.

Considering A to be 0, and Z to be 25, you can simple rotate using modular arithmetic as `encrypted_char = (char + shift) % 26`. In our case, the letters `'a'` and `'z'` are not on the number 1, but we can easily solve this by substracting, and then adding, the starting value

```
A = ord('a')
def lowercase_rotate_cypher( message, shift):
    accumulator = []
    for character in message:
        c = A + ( ( ord(character) + shift - A ) % 26)
        accumulator.append( chr(c) )
    return ''.join(accumulator)
```

In your case, the `shift=5` and message is passed from input.

Comment: I'd suggest two more improvements: 1) **don't** use global variables - pass the input string as parameter to the function and **return** the result from function; 2) make use of the fact that `ord("v") - ord("a")` is 21.

Comment: Only now realised this is just a simple shift encryption. I added the lowercase rot function example.